# Trying to understand the following AyncImageLoader

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

```
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.util.HashMap;

 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;


public class AsyncImageLoader {
private HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>> imageCache;
HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>> drawableMap = new HashMap<String,    SoftReference<Drawable>>();


public AsyncImageLoader() {
    //HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>> drawableMap = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>>();
}

public Drawable loadDrawable(final String imageUrl, final ImageCallback imageCallback) {

    if (drawableMap.containsKey(imageUrl)) {
        SoftReference<Drawable> softReference = imageCache.get(imageUrl);
        Drawable drawable = softReference.get();
        if (drawable != null) {
            return drawable;
        }
    }
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            imageCallback.imageLoaded((Drawable) message.obj, imageUrl);
        }
    };

    //this is the new thread that download the image from url
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Drawable drawable = loadImageFromUrl(imageUrl);
            imageCache.put(imageUrl, new SoftReference<Drawable>(drawable));
            Message message = handler.obtainMessage(0, drawable);
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }.start();
    return null;
}

public static Drawable loadImageFromUrl(String url) {
    return null;
    // ...
}

public interface ImageCallback {
    public void imageLoaded(Drawable imageDrawable, String imageUrl);
}
```

}

OK, My understanding is such:
1)Check to see if the image in the cache, if it is then return drawable;
2)If not, then create a new handler to send a message to UI thread with Drawable as object, and this handler won't send until the imageloaded callback function is called
3)create a new thread to initiate download image from url.

4)
specifically the sequence for handler happens in this order
A)Message message = handler.obtainMessage(0, drawable);
B) public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                imageCallback.imageLoaded((Drawable) message.obj, imageUrl);
            }
C) handler.sendMessage(message);

The issue I have is Number 4, I am abit unclear, obtainmessage(0, drawable)? obtain from where? where's the source? How do I know where it come from, UI thread or others? So, once obtained that message, the message handler would do the callback.  public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                imageCallback.imageLoaded((Drawable) message.obj, imageUrl);
            }

finally it send the message with drawable as payload.    handler.sendMessage(message);
but how do I know where its sending? Does it always have UI thread as final destination?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically -- there are two threads here, the main UI thread that most of this code is executed in, and the download thread defined at the bottom.

the obtainMessage call simply returns a message object from a pool, which is cheaper than instantiating a new one.  It's analogous to a constructor in this usage.

since the handler is defined in the UI thread, the handleMessage method is executed in the UI thread as well.  The message itself is simply a way of getting the drawable from the download thread to the UI thread, as well as trigger the callback, when the download is complete.

So basically all this code is doing is:  if the drawable exists in the (SoftReference) cache, then return it.  Otherwise, get a reference to a handler and start a thread which downloads the drawable.  When that thread is done downloading, it creates a message and sends it to the handler, which in turns calls imageCallback.imageLoaded and passes the newly downloaded drawable.